# Games can't be shown in full screen

Tags: windows, hp-laptop, amd-vision

My games can't view in full screen, What can I do? I have try to set full screen from the AMD VISION Control center but nothing has changed. I have HP 635

Comment: Would you please describe your problem a bit more precise? What games do not work in fullscreen? what happens if you set the game video setting to fullscreen? Have you tried alt + return? What are your operating system and graphics card?